# Is the wording "parametric integral" standard in English?

Tags: integration, terminology

For a measured space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$, a set $T$ and a map $$f : T \times \Omega \to \mathbb R^n$$ we say in French that $$F(t) = \int_\Omega f(t,\omega) \ d\mu(\omega)$$ is a **parametric integral** (see [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9grale_param%C3%A9trique) article).

Is **parametric integral** making sense as a translation into English? I raise the question as the French article has for associated English article [Differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), which doesn't have the same meaning.

If not, what is a well accepted wording for the concept of French "intégrale paramétrique"?

Comment: In European Portuguese the term is used as in french. I think the term makes perfect sense (and more importantly it is intuitive) in english too: an integral with a parameter $t$ (though I think it isn't commonly used). Regarding the Wikipedia "translation" (or rather correspondence), I assume the articles are connected because parametric integrals are closely related to "differentiation under the integral sign". A major point, I think, is that (in my experience) in english-speaking countries they do without the term "parametric integral", they work around the concept without naming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While *parametric integral* seems not commonly used, it  seems fairly understandable. I’ll then follow on using it in writing as suggested by [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud).